# Explanation of the logic inside for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, random

Im a newbie in C#. I have seen a code for random password generator. I need help in understanding the logic inside the for loop function to further understand how it works:

```
{
    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}
```

below is the full code

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
        "0123456789" +
        "@!#*&_";
    var stringChars = new char[8]; 
    var random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
    {
        stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
    }

    return new string (stringChars);
```

Comment: `random.Next(chars.Length)` will return a random number between 0 and `chars.Length-1`. That number is then used to index into the `chars` array to get a random character from it. That character is then put in `stringsChars[i]`. Since `i` goes from 0 to `stringChars.Length-1` this has the effect of filling `stringChars` with random characters taken from `chars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's `stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];` down

1. `chars` is of a  `String` type
2. chars[...] is to get an item an in the string array in some index, i.e `chars[0]` will 
   give you the char 'a'
3. `random.Next(X)` is to get a random number between 0 and the number written the brackets
4. `chars.Length` will give you the length  the chars string, meaning the amount the chars that are in the string
5. from [4] and [3] `random.Next(chars.Length)` you will get a random number between 0 and the length of your string
6. from [5] and [2] you will get the random char in you string

meaning in that line you will insert for each  place in  `stringChars` a random char from you `chars` string

**TIP** 
Try to always break a line that you dont understand to a smaller segment(s) and then analyze them separately and then add all together

Comment: Hi @styx, additional question, how will I make sure that every value in stringChars has the upper, lower, number and special character when generated?

Comment: @AnnVi you can sperate your chars to different strings, one with only lower, one with only upper, etc. **OR** your random function can run once from 0-23(lower letters) 24-47(upper letters) etc